# Java daemon with web frontend communication

Tags: java, linux, communication, daemon, frontend

I am starting a new Java project and am stuck at the architectural stage.

The idea is to create a Java daemon process (I am designing this for Linux) which will have a web frontend (jsp?, php?, ...) running in Tomcat. The daemon would periodically poll for mysql data and execute external scripts and programs.

The web frontend would be used to view the data from mysql and signal the daemon to start a new task (e.g. poll the tasklist command on a windows client every x seconds) and this would be presented to the browser.

My questions are:

1.) Is this daemon + web frontend a good combination? I read that it could be done with two servlets with one being loaded as soon as tomcat was up, but this restricts me in communication with external programs and using other system calls, or am I wrong?

2.) Which web framework would be the best fit for this kind of situation? (GWT, Spring, ?)

3.) If going with the daemon + web frontend combination how would the two communicate (UNIX sockets or HTTP sockets or ???) as polling mysql to often is not what I would like to do?

4.) Are JavaServerPages a good fit for this or would it be to complex for this situation?

My earlier experience is making a few Java swing apps, a webstart app and some php web pages.

I would appreciate any suggestions as to how I should go about designing this.

Thanks!

Peter

Answer (score 0):

I am not much clear on the question but I will try to answer your question, not sure if the will make sense as I am not clear on the context.

1) Yes you can go with that combination all servers are threads. Not sure why you require 2 servlets but you can start you daemon in ServletContextLister. Having a daemon in Servlet is not recommended. How is it restricting in communication with external programs or using other system calls ?

2) Any framework or no framework at all. The 2 examples you have given are for totally very different things.

3) Why does the 2 required to communicate ? the front end gets the data from mysql or the daemon. From the question it seems it gets the data from database.

4) All that you can do with frameworks you can also do it yourself. Only things is that frameworks helps.

Comment: How would the front end get the data from the daemon? By which way?

Comment: If its a common data (shared for all clients) then the daemon can put that data in ServletContext. The client then needs to get that data from there. Not its depends how you want the client to be ? Does the client need to refresh the data automatically or will the user go to some specific link and sees the data ? It is a automatic refresh the you need to use ajax polling